# How can I start two commands in command prompt with a "start" command?

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

What I want to do is execute more than one command line in a start command(not just in a regular command prompt because I don't want it to close). Here is what I have:

```
start "x" /D "C:\Program Files\x" /I call y
```

everything's fine, except I want to also execute echo off (and maybe cls, but that's not crucial).

Comment: Why not use it to start a batch file that then does the echo off and cls and executes the program X?

Comment: The thing is, If I do that it will just run the echo off for the initial window, not the new window.

Comment: Not if what you are starting is a batch file which sets echo off and does the cls.

Comment: yeah, that was my fix. I just wanted some way to do it once and have it affect all calls